# Как найти конкретные значение количество друзей, количество фотографии в Вконтакте

Tags: python, html, вконтакте, beautiful-soup

Как вытянуть количество друзей и количество фотографии. Как видно может быть и так что очередность может быть и не такая, может быть так что категории подписчиков нету, поэтому группа первая и вторая может не пойти. Может быть такая ситуация когда фото нет, а друзья есть. Т.е. если нету друзей то вернуть значение 0. Вывести количество друзей и количество фотографии в отдельные переменные

```
....

    <div class="counts_module"><a class="page_counter" href="/friends?id=61*****2&amp;section=all" onclick="return page.showPageMembers(event, 61*****62, 'friends');">
      <div class="count">86</div>
      <div class="label">друзей</div>
    </a><a class="page_counter" onclick="return page.showPageMembers(event, 61****62, 'fans');">
      <div class="count">2</div>
      <div class="label">подписчика</div>
    </a><a class="page_counter" href="/albums*****?profile=1" onclick="return showAlbums(61****2, {noHistory: true}, event);">
      <div class="count">11</div>
      <div class="label">фотографий</div>
    </a><a class="page_counter" href="/audios****" onclick="return page.showPageAudios(event, 611263162);">
      <div class="count">94</div>
      <div class="label">аудиозаписи</div>
    </a></div>

....
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

По идее лучше парсить html не регулярными выражениями, а, к примеру, `lxml` библиотекой. В конкретном примере, в главном `div`-е создаём словарь `user`, проходим по всем узлам с тегом `a` и записываем в словарь текст из `div`-а, которые имеют в себе атрибут `class` о значениями `count` и `label`. ч

Пример кода, работающего с `xpath`:

```
from lxml import html

user = {}

doc = html.fromstring(raw_html)
for node in doc.xpath('/div/a'):

    label = node.xpath('/div[contains(@class,"label")]')
    count = node.xpath('/div[contains(@class,"count")]')
    user[label[0].text] = count[0].text
```

Примеры использования XPath: https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method

Comment: в моем коде было использовано html = driver.page_source

Comment: в моем коде было использовано html = driver.page_source, через selenium. При использовании вашего кода. Выдает ошибку  doc = html.fromstring(raw_html)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fromstring'

Comment: Видимо, у вас конфликт имён. Переименуйте результат driver.page_source во что-нибудь другое. :)